# What are the tags for firefox releases in mozilla's repository?

Tags: firefox, mercurial, mozilla, spidermonkey

I want to recompile the source code of SpiderMonkey.

The mercurial repository is accessible from https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/ , but I am having a hard time to understand what tags are used to keep track of the released versions.

The tags are [here](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/tags), but I see nothing that sounds like a release.

What is for example the revision used to compile Firefox 65.0.2 ? How can I determine it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong repository. Final releases are tagged in the [mozilla-release repository](https://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-release), which has [per release tags](https://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-release/tags), including the [`FIREFOX_65_0_2_RELEASE` tag](https://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-release/rev/FIREFOX_65_0_2_RELEASE).

Mozilla-central is only used for nightly releases. Changesets landed there are periodically merged into the [mozilla-beta](https://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-beta) repository, and after several beta releases, when the final release is made the changes are pulled into the mozilla-release repository and tagged. See [*The Firefox Release Process*](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Release_Management/Release_Process) on MozillaWiki:

> [image: Mozilla release process illustration, showing how mozilla-cental feeds mozilla-beta which in turn feeds mozilla-release]
>
> ### From mozilla-central to mozilla-release
>
> - Firefox Nightly is released every 12 hours with all the changes landed on mozilla-central.
> - Every 6 to 8 weeks, we merge the code from mozilla-central to our mozilla-beta branch. The mozilla-beta branch should now only get patches aimed at stabilizing the release. Any patch on mozilla-central that we want backported to our mozilla-beta branch should follow the approval rules for uplifts.
>
> [...]
>
> - At the end of the Beta cycle, a final build is validated by our QA and tagged for release into the mozilla-release branch.

Because the beta process picks up specific commits from mozilla-central into the mozilla-beta branch only, there is no way to build a final release from the mozilla-central repository.